# Aggregate sum of means where grouping is not nested

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following Table:

```
set.seed(4) 
DT=data.table(GroupeID=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=4)
          ,ID=letters[rep(sample(1:26,5),times=2,each=2)]
          ,numVar=runif(20)
          );DT

   GroupeID ID     numVar
 1:        A  p 0.26042777
 2:        A  p 0.72440589
 3:        A  a 0.90609215
 4:        A  a 0.94904022
 5:        B  h 0.07314447
 6:        B  h 0.75467503
 7:        B  g 0.28600062
 8:        B  g 0.10005352
 9:        C  r 0.95406878
10:        C  r 0.41560712
11:        C  p 0.45510242
12:        C  p 0.97105566
13:        D  a 0.58398798
14:        D  a 0.96220462
15:        D  h 0.76170240
16:        D  h 0.71450854
17:        E  g 0.99661286
18:        E  g 0.50627089
19:        E  r 0.48994324
20:        E  r 0.64916137
```

I am trying to add a column which shows the sum of the means of `numVar` for each `ID` by `GroupeID`.
This is of course not the same as simply adding up `numVar` by `GroupeID`, since an `ID` can occur in multiple `GroupeID`. The desired column `sumPG` can be created in two steps:

```
DT[, meanID:=mean(numVar), by=ID]
DT[, sumPG:=sum(meanID), by=GroupeID]
```

Is this possible in one step in `data.table`? I've tried this:

```
DT[, sumPG:=sum(DT[,.(GroupeID, mean(numVar)),by=ID]$V2), by=GroupeID];DT
```

but this does not do the grouping. Can I somehow subset the inner `DT` to only include `GroupeID` from the outer group *after* grouping by `ID`?

Comment: you can apply the principle of the dplyr syntax to data.table syntax -- basically you're doing a self join of one aggregated table back to the main table

Comment: You know about chaining, right? `DT[, meanID:=mean(numVar), by=ID][, sumPG:=sum(meanID), by=GroupeID]`

Comment: one of the reasons I would like to do this in one step is to not produce this additional column `meanID` which I do not want and have to delete afterwards. But sure, this is a possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DT[, meanID:=mean(numVar), by=ID][, sumPG:=sum(meanID), by=GroupeID][,-c("meanID")]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
  library(dplyr)
  DT %>% 
   group_by(GroupeID, ID) %>% 
   summarise(meanNumVar = mean(numVar)) %>% 
   summarise(sumNumVar = sum(meanNumVar)) %>% 
   right_join(x, by="GroupeID")

# A tibble: 20 x 4
   GroupeID sumNumVar ID    numVar
   <fct>        <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
 1 A            1.42  p     0.260 
 2 A            1.42  p     0.724 
 3 A            1.42  a     0.906 
 4 A            1.42  a     0.949 
 5 B            0.607 h     0.0731
 6 B            0.607 h     0.755 
 7 B            0.607 g     0.286 
 8 B            0.607 g     0.100 
 9 C            1.40  r     0.954 
10 C            1.40  r     0.416 
11 C            1.40  p     0.455 
12 C            1.40  p     0.971 
13 D            1.51  a     0.584 
14 D            1.51  a     0.962 
15 D            1.51  h     0.762 
16 D            1.51  h     0.715 
17 E            1.32  g     0.997 
18 E            1.32  g     0.506 
19 E            1.32  r     0.490 
20 E            1.32  r     0.649
```

Is that what you are looking for? I am not sure I got your question right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't use dplyr and therefore looking for a data.table solution. I will edit my post accordingly